# Why is Google Sheets query not suppressing header, when there's a calculated field?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-visualization, google-query-language

I do a simple query on this table,

[image: Google Sheet Table]

| Row 1 | Row 2 | Row 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 |

with a calculated column (it is a column that does not exist in the Spreadsheet with the fixed "C" value, that I managed to create with upper('c') value.

If I want to filter out the header, it does not work. (if I take out the calculated column, it works again). To take out header I use the url "headers=0" param.

### Version with the calculated column:

```
function testSQL() 
{
  const fileKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const sheetName="Sheet1";
  const formatType="csv";
  
  var queryA="SELECT A, B, C, upper('c')";
  var queryURLA = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileKey + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:' + formatType + '&headers=0&sheet=' + sheetName + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(queryA);

  //Logger.log(queryURLA);

  var retA = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryURLA, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
  var retAV = Utilities.parseCsv(retA,",");

  Logger.log(retAV);

  return retAV;
}
```

Execution log (**Wrong! a strange header appears**)

```
7:35:20 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:35:21 AM  Info    [[, , , upper("c"())], [1, 2, 3, C], [4, 5, 6, C], [7, 8, 9, C], [10, 11, 12, C], [13, 14, 15, C]]
7:35:21 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

### Version without the calculated column:

```
function testSQL() 
{
  const fileKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const sheetName="Sheet1";
  const formatType="csv";
  
  var queryA="SELECT A, B, C";
  var queryURLA = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + fileKey + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:' + formatType + '&headers=0&sheet=' + sheetName + '&tq=' + encodeURIComponent(queryA);

  //Logger.log(queryURLA);

  var retA = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryURLA, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getContentText();
  var retAV = Utilities.parseCsv(retA,",");

  Logger.log(retAV);

  return retAV;
}
```

Result (**Correct, no header**):

```
Execution log
7:31:59 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:31:59 AM  Info    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
7:32:00 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Offset does not solve the issue.

Does anybody confirm it is not my fault?
Any solution / workaround?

Comment: What are your expected values using your showing Spreadsheet?

Comment: [[ 1, 2, 3, C], [7, 8, 9, C], [10, 11, 12, C], [13, 14, 15, C]], i.e. the first row (which does not exist in the sheet) is not present.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your issue has already been resolved. I'm glad about it.

Comment: Hi, I was provided a workaround that works. Totally unclear why the behaviour happens...

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: `Does anybody confirm it is not my fault`. Yes, I can. It's not your fault. It's known behavior.

Comment: ok now i put the table. I did not share the file for privacy reasons. Hoping that the known behavior is only affecting the case I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`retAV.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) before the line `return retAV`.

#### Example:

```js
var retAV = Utilities.parseCsv(retA,",");
retAV.shift()
Logger.log(retAV);
return retAV;
```

#### Execution log

```
10:14:59 AM Notice  Execution started
10:15:00 AM Info    [[1, 2, 3, C], [4, 5, 6, C], [7, 8, 9, C], [10, 11, 12, C], [13, 14, 15, C]]
10:15:00 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea about why it happens?

Comment: I think it's just to identify that the data isn't exactly as it appears in the sheet, though can't find supporting documentation to verify this for sure

Comment: I think that this is a good modification.